# how to print file path in text box using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i want to print the file path in the text box. I have just created the text box and a button which invoke the choose file window. Now i have to print the selected file path.

my code is:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, Tkconstants 
from Tkinter import * 

def open():
    File = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='r',title='Choose a file')
    for f in File:
        yourName.insert(1.0, f.read())

root = Tk() 
custName = StringVar(None)
yourName = Entry(root, textvariable=custName)
yourName.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
yourName.update()
yourName.focus_set()
yourName.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20,anchor='n')
yourName.place(y = 25, x = 100, width = 525, height = 25)

button = Button(root, text='Take a Picture',command = open)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
button.place( x = 650, y = 25)

root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: There is no point in calling pack, and then immediately calling place. Choose one or the other (and pack or grid are almost always better than choosing place)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the path of the selected file, use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`.

```
def open():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
    custName.set(filename)
```